# Relation between spin and polarization of photon?

Tags: photons, quantum-spin, spin-models

What is the possible spin configuration of photon?
 And does spin has any relation with polarization?

Answer (score 0):

Photons are quantum mechanical entities,  have spin 1 ( sorry missprint caught by md2perpe), and because they at the same time have mass 0 their spin can point either in the direction of their motion, or against: +1 or -1, this is the only polarization it can have. Light , which emerges from zillions of  photons does have polarization.

[This graphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_angular_momentum_of_light) shows  clearly how the polarization of light emerges from the huge number of photons, which superimposed (their wave functions) generate the classical polarized light.

[image: angmomlight]

Rght handed light polarization emerges with photons having their spin -1, and left handed +1.

Comment: Photons don't have spin 0. They have spin 1.

Comment: @md2perpe thanks for correction.of course,wrong hit :(